# Error adding a convential sign up and github sign up together in a django project

Tags: python, html, django, django-allauth

I am doing a django book store project which has a successful sign up function. I followed WS Vincent's tutorial to connect Github signup (https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-allauth-tutorial) and I have come across an error when integrating it.

TemplateSyntaxError at /

Invalid block tag on line 16: 'provider_login_url', expected 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Below is the code for the major areas of my project.
home.html

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Homepage</h1>
<img class="bookcover" src="{% static 'images/djangoforprofessionals.jpg' %}">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Hi {{ user.email }}!</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">Log Out</a></p>
{% else %}
    <p>You are not logged in</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Log In</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="{% provider_login_url 'github' %}">Sign Up</a></p> 
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I am not familiar with HTML but I take the two sign up lines are not meant to be put one after the other.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, it seems like you forget to load `{% load socialaccount %}`.

[Reference](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html#social-account-tags)